# React intl FormattedDate format issue on test snapshots

Tags: reactjs, react-intl

I'm using the FormattedDate component from react-intl (v6.4.4) package to display a date:

```
<span className={styles.CreationDate}>
  <FormattedDate
     value={created}
     weekday="long"
     day="numeric"
     hour="2-digit"
     minute="2-digit"
     dayPeriod="long"
     month="long"
 />
</span>
```

Everything seems to works fine but I have a problem with my test snapshots (I'm using @testing-library/react to generate them).
Specifically, when I generate them locally I see something like this:

```
<span
  class="CreationDate"
>
   Tuesday, February 1 at 01:00 AM
</span>
```

but when I generate them via CI that runs all my tests before deploying the code I see a different date format:

```
<span
  class="CreationDate"
>
  Tuesday, February 1, 01:00 AM
</span>
```

this is likely due to a different timezone in which the CI run.
Is there a way to force a specific date format to generate my snaps ?

Comment: try adding the prop : `timeZone="utc"` in your `FormattedDate`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I want, this date should be displayed in the local timezone of the user moreover, the problem about the format of the date remains, the word "at" is replaced by a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this would be to mock the FormattedDate component

```js
jest.mock('react-intl', () => {
  const rest = jest.requireActual('react-intl');
  return { ...rest, FormattedDate: () => 'Tuesday, February 1 at 01:00 AM' };
});
```

Comment: Just tried your solution but it has no effect on my snapshots, is there probably another way to mock that component?

Comment: Whoops, the ...rest overwrites the mock, try it the other way around. I'll edit the answer aswell

Comment: oh right, I confirm that it solves my problem, many thanks!